# How to use EXIST in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, exists, not-exists

How would I go about using the Exists query to display the author information for authors who have more than one book but no book sales?
I was thinking that this was the solution, but then again I am not sure. From what I can tell there are no authors that have not sold any books. I did not receive an error. Just an empty set. It's late for me so maybe I am missing something:

```
 SELECT author_id
      , author_name_last
      , author_name_first
 FROM a_bkinfo.authors
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
     FROM a_bkinfo.book_authors BS
     JOIN a_bkorders.order_details OD on BS.book_id = OD.book_id
     WHERE quantity > 1

         )
 AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT MAX(orders) 
             FROM (  
                  SELECT book_id
                      ,  count(order_id) AS orders
                    FROM a_bkorders.order_details
                   GROUP BY book_id
                  HAVING count(order_id) = 1
                  ) t
        )
 ;
```

Comment: Why do you specifically wish to use EXISTS?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your table definitions, it's hard to say but I would do something like this:

```
SELECT  author_id
  , author_name_last
  , author_name_first
FROM a_bkinfo.authors
WHERE
    -- Number of book by the author is greater than 1 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM -- table of books (a_bkinfo.book_authors?)
     WHERE -- book was written by a_bkinfo.authors.author_id) > 1

    -- Number of book sales is zero
    AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * 
           FROM -- table of book orders (a_bkorders.order_details)
           JOIN -- table of books joining the orders with the corresponding books 
           WHERE -- book was written by a_bkinfo.authors.author_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing 2 related things:  neither subquery actually references any columns from the outer table a_bkinfo.authors, so neither of them is actually selecting the things you want to select.

If you pull your subqueries out and run them individually, it appears as if they will both run by themselves **which is wrong**.  In the outer query, you need to give a_bkinfo.authors an alias such as 'a' and then then inner subqueries need to be `WHERE [something] = a.author_id` or `WHERE [something] = a.book_id`.

If the query were logically sound, it would work, but would not be optimal, because you're not likely to get the same efficiency from `EXISTS` as you would from `JOIN`.

As it is now, the first subquery is returning EXISTS = TRUE for every author in the outer query, as long as one author, any author, has written at least 2 books... and the second subquery is returning EXISTS = TRUE for every author in the outer query, because it's calculating and returning the largest count of orders for "any" author, every time.

There's also a flaw in the database design as far as what I can see here, because a_bkinfo.authors contains both an author_id, which presumably represents an id in an authors table, but also contains copies of the author's first and last names, which should not be copied onto every book but should be fetched from that authors table with another join.

But here's a more optimal query, based on what I can work out from your data.

```
SELECT author_id,
       author_name_last,
       author_name_first,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(a.book_id)) as books_written,
       COUNT(od.order_id) as order_count
  FROM a_bkinfo.authors a
  LEFT JOIN  
  JOIN a_bkorders.order_details od ON od.book_id = a.book_id
 GROUP BY a.author_id
HAVING written_count > 1
   AND order_count = 0;
```

For every author_id in the bkinfo.authors table, we'll count how many books they've written by counting the unique book_id values we find, then we'll count the number of order_ids, and the `HAVING` clause restructs the resultset to written_count > 1 and order_count = 0;

The size of the orders table might make it such that `EXISTS` to check orders would be faster because a large number of orders are for books whose author only wrote one book.